# DownloadStringAsync has return type void. So how do I await it?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await

Looking at the documentation here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144202(v=vs.110).aspx, `DownloadStringAsync` has return type `void`, which means VS gives me an error

> Cannot await 'void'

So how am I supposed to use that method?

Comment: From the page you linked to: “When the download completes, the DownloadStringCompleted event is raised. Your application must handle this event to receive notification. The downloaded string is available in the Result property.”

Comment: @Ryan That is funky. I see an *Async method called without an await in front of it. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadstringcompleted(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: you have to add an event (as outlined in your referenced documentation) - for an example how to do this see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadstringcompleted(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7129256/how-to-use-string-in-webclient-downloadstringasync-url

Comment: @user7127000 That *Async method has been around since before the `Task` type or `async`/`await` existed. That's why.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting a WebClient method to async / await](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13240915/converting-a-webclient-method-to-async-await)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use [DownloadStringTaskAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194294(v=vs.110).aspx) which supports the async/await pattern

`public Task<string> DownloadStringTaskAsync(Uri address)`